# What does this .htaccess code mean?

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* ./index.php
```

I think it means if the url doesn't match a file or directory on the server go to /index.php?

Can anybody confirm?

Comment: yes, except it goes to the index.php of the directory containing the .htaccess (which is not necessarily the same as /index.php as you write)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes is the short answer. But usually `./index.php` has an `[L,QSA]` suffix/qualifier, so the query part of a URI request is also passed on to it.

Comment: If I had to remove this rule, what would happen in the case of file/directory not found? 404 error?

Comment: If you remove `RewriteRule`, the previous `RewriteCond` directives will have no effect

Comment: Sorry, I mean if I remove the entire block?

Comment: If you remove everything or delete the .htaccess file containing those elements, then Apache will treat your site like any other, i.e. it will look for folder, files and render them if they exist, otherwise you get a 404

Answer (score 0):

What this is doing:

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

If it can't find a directory with the name

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

If it can't find a file with the name

> RewriteRule .* ./index.php

Load the index.php next to the .htaccess file.

To answer Anthony's question regarding what would happen if it where removed<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247174/what-does-this-htaccess-code-mean?rq=1#comment4599955_4247217)</sup> <sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247174/what-does-this-htaccess-code-mean?rq=1#comment4600063_4247217)</sup>,

It would try and access the directory or file. If it fails, instead of defaulting to the `index.php` it would simply give the default web servers 404 error.

Right now, it allows the application to either show the default page, or handle the request through it in some fashion.